# URLForResource() returns always nil, swift 2.3, iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to test something, and need access to the file which is in the same directory as the test class (in fact in sub-directory). I am trying to do it like this:

```
let fileURL = testBundle.URLForResource("MasterCalendar", withExtension: "ics", subdirectory: "Calendars")
```

I also tried it like this:

```
let fileURL = testBundle.URLForResource("MasterCalendar", withExtension: "ics")
```

My class is called ParserTest. The file I am trying to access is located as shown:
[image]

I tried to get the file path:

```
 if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MasterCalendar", ofType: "ics", inDirectory: "Calendars") {
        print("PATH: ", filePath)
    }
```

I tried to remove inDirectory, and put also "CallInTests/Calendar". Nothing worked. 
The file itself is added in the Target for tests:

[image]

AND for the project:
[image]

Regardless of what I do, the fileURL returns always nil.

Comment: Consider that yellow folders are virtual groups, not real directories in the file system (these are blue).

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear to me how your `testBundle` is defined, but this works for me:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: YourClassHere.self)
```

So in your case that would be:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: ParserTest.self)
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
if let path = bundle.path(forResource: "MasterCalendar", ofType: "ics") {
  //magic goes here
}
```

#### Swift 2.3 version

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: ParserTest.self)

if let path = bundle.pathForResource("MasterCalendar", ofType: "ics") {
   //magic still goes here :)
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following way :

```
let testBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
let fileURL = testBundle.URLForResource("MasterCalendar", withExtension: "ics")
XCTAssertNotNil(fileURL)
```